# Docker compse build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am extremely new to docker, and was testing out a docker image and it comes with a docker-compose.yaml file, and when i try to run it i keep getting an error message on when it comes to the build: ./nginx

I get the following error message

```
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
unable to prepare context: path "./nginx" not found
```

Docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.11'
# Defining the compose version
services:

 # Nginx server
 nginx:
 
   # Build context
   build: ./nginx
   
   # Mapping machine and container ports
   ports:
     - 1337:80
```

I am not sure what the build: ./nginx actually does.

Comment: Where is your compose file in context with the rest of your code? My guess is you need to change this `build: ./nginx` to this `build: .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **build** key in docker-compose.yaml is used to specify the location of a **Dockerfile** from which the **docker engine** will build a *docker image*

In your case, docker will look for a file named **Dockerfile** inside a directory called nginx

You have two options:

1/ If you have the **Dockerfile**, fix the path by referring to the directory where it exists
for example if you have

TestDirectory:

|_ docker-compose.yaml

|_ Dockerfile

Just type " build: . "

2/ change build key with image: nginx:latest (for example)

Comment: Wow, perfect answer, i understand it now. Thank you you so much for that.